# ASP.NET Core HttpPost Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

My ASP.NET Core Web API `POST` method is not working properly. How to resolve that issue?

Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddEmployee([FromBody] dynamic employeeRequest)
{
    employeeRequest.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

    await _fullStackDbContext.Employees.AddAsync(employeeRequest);
    await _fullStackDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(employeeRequest);
}
```

Error:

[image]

Comment: Why do you think `dynamic employeeRequest` should work? This is C#, not JavaScript. You need to pass an `Employee` to `AddASync()`.

Comment: @CodeCaster,Previously used:  public async Task<IActionResult> AddEmployee([FromBody] Employee employeeRequest){}.But at that time API not working.when use dynamic I can get UI Jason parameters to the API with above issue

Comment: You don't want to use your entities as API models. Create a separate DTO that corresponds to the JSON you want to send. Then map that DTO to your entity.